# How to pass two parameters in one function on separate occasions?

Tags: javascript, html

**Intro**

I am trying to make a rock, paper scissors game. I need to save 2 player inputs in 1 function (preferably). So when playerOne clicks on "rock" and playerTwo clicks on "paper" it will save that too.

Separate variables, same function.

**Requirements**

- Can't use any libraries, must be 100% vanilla JS.

**What I currently have**

```js
function getPlayerOption(playerOne, playerTwo) {
  console.log(playerOne);
  console.log(playerTwo);
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#player_turn {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Rock, paper, scissors!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Player <span id="player_turn">1</span> pick an option!</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <p onclick="getPlayerOption('rock')" id="rock">
        Rock
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <p onclick="getPlayerOption('paper')" id="paper">
        Paper
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <p onclick="getPlayerOption('scissors')" id="scissors">
        Scissors
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Output that I want**

First click is on "rock" and second click is one "paper" output in console will be:

```
Console;
-> "rock"
-> "paper"
```

Thank you for your time and efforts.

Comment: You could create a class for the game and store the inputs in member variables.

Comment: You can create a class object and store the two responses one by one into two variables and then call the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a class for the game and store the inputs in member variables.

```js
class Game {
  playerOne = null;
  playerTwo = null;
  getPlayerOption(input) {
    if (this.playerOne) {
      this.playerTwo = input;
      this.print();
      this.reset();
    } else {
      this.playerOne = input;
    }
  }
  print() {
    console.log(this.playerOne);
    console.log(this.playerTwo);
  }
  reset() {
    this.playerOne = null;
    this.playerTwo = null;
  }
}

const game = new Game();
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#player_turn {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Rock, paper, scissors!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Player <span id="player_turn">1</span> pick an option!</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <p onclick="game.getPlayerOption('rock')" id="rock">
        Rock
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <p onclick="game.getPlayerOption('paper')" id="paper">
        Paper
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <p onclick="game.getPlayerOption('scissors')" id="scissors">
        Scissors
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh! This looks great, would you mind elaborating a bit on what exactly you did here?

Comment: @Lar I created a class with two member variables and a method. The method stores the inputs in the member variables.

Comment: thanks, I understand. I'm going to read some documentation about method. Not familiar with that at all. Thanks for elaborating.

Comment: Is there a way I can reset the classes and method after 2 times? So if 2 people go, it resets and then it goes again.

Comment: @Lar Yes, I fixed it

Comment: Hi @jabaa, I was wondering, since I'm working on further stages of r.p.s is there a way i can switch out the print/switch statement with another function which compares the answers? Because everytime I delete the console/print bit, I get scribble lines.

Comment: @Lar I'm not sure how to answer your question. Yes, of course you can replace the functions.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the fast and kind response. Okay, I have no idea how to do that, because it keeps saying I'm doing it wrong, do you reccommend me doing this in or outside of the class?

Comment: @Lar This seems to be a new question. Stack Overflow is a Q&A platform. Opinions, discussions and recommendations should be avoided. If you have new specific programming question you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Store values to global scope, have one value that will keep value of current player, any call to your `getPlayerOption` will automatically switch to next player.

```js
// Here are all values that are cast so far. Not in function, because it would be overwritten on each function call
var values = {
  player_1: [],
  player_2: []
};

// Current playing player
var currentPlayer = '1';

function getPlayerOption(value) {
  // Get type of player dynamically
  playerType = 'player_' + currentPlayer;
  console.log('Player ' + playerType + ' casts ' + value);

  // Save value of current player
  values[playerType].push(value);
  
  // Switch to next player
  currentPlayer = currentPlayer == '1' ? '2' : '1';
  
  console.log('Moves so far', values);
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

#player_turn {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Rock, paper, scissors!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Player <span id="player_turn">1</span> pick an option!</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <p onclick="getPlayerOption('rock')" id="rock">
        Rock
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <p onclick="getPlayerOption('paper')" id="paper">
        Paper
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <p onclick="getPlayerOption('scissors')" id="scissors">
        Scissors
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed description + explanationo in the code! I appreciate it.